# PhoneGap / Cordova force iPhone 5 size on iPad Device

Tags: cordova

Can I force an application to have an iPhone 5 size on my iPad?

I'm using my iPad as the only test device but I would like to test the app in iPhone 5 size so is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy the APP for iPhone only. If you run an iPhone Application on the iPad, it is automatically in the size of an iPhone.

You need to set up the device under your General Projekt Tab in XCode.

Check out here:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html

Comment: I'm running this with "phonegap build ios" do I have to do this EVERY time I build it?

Comment: It should save your preferences, so you dont need to set up again.

Comment: Well I did that but it didn't work. The problem is, I'm not "deploying" to the iPad, I'm using the "phonegap app" and it still shows up as iPad app. Is there any other setting besides xcode I need to consider?

Comment: So you are deploying your app with the Command Line Interface? There is a iOS settings XML File, where you set the values for the compiler. Check this out: http://devgirl.org/2013/09/05/phonegap-3-0-stuff-you-should-know/ - there is a "target-device" - try to insert "iphone"

Comment: Well tried everything written here, no luck. If I change the config file of the main www will is also propagate to the builds?

Comment: BTW, I've no problems running it correctly on emulator. I only want to force it in iPhone size on the companion app from phonegap.